# Retrieve each token from a file according to specific criteria

Tags: c++, lexer

I'm trying to create a lexer for a functional language, one of the methods of which should allow, on each call, to return the next token of a file.
For example :

```
func main() {
    var MyVar : integer = 3+2;
}
```

So I would like every time the next method is called, the next token in that sequence is returned; in that case, it would look like this :

```
func
main
(
)
{
var
MyVar
:
integer
=
3
+
2
;
}
```

Except that the result I get is not what I expected:

```
func
main(
)

{





var
MyVar
:

integer
=

3+
2

}
```

Here is my method:

```
token_t Lexer::next() {
    token_t ret;
    std::string token_tmp;
    bool IsSimpleQuote = false; // check string   --> "..."
    bool IsDoubleQuote = false; // check char     --> '...'
    bool IsComment = false;     // check comments --> `...`
    bool IterWhile = true;
    while (IterWhile) {
        bool IsInStc = (IsDoubleQuote || IsSimpleQuote || IsComment);
        std::ifstream file_tmp(this->CurrentFilename);
        if (this->eof) break;
        char chr = this->File.get();
        char next = file_tmp.seekg(this->CurrentCharIndex + 1).get();
        ++this->CurrentCharInCurrentLineIndex;
        ++this->CurrentCharIndex;
        {
            if (!IsInStc && !IsComment && chr == '`') IsComment = true; else if (!IsInStc && IsComment && chr == '`') { IsComment = false; continue; }
            if (IsComment) continue;
            if (!IsInStc && chr == '"') IsDoubleQuote = true;
            else if (!IsInStc && chr == '\'') IsSimpleQuote = true;
            else if (IsDoubleQuote && chr == '"') IsDoubleQuote = false;
            else if (IsSimpleQuote && chr == '\'') IsSimpleQuote = false;
        }
        if (chr == '\n') {
            ++this->CurrentLineIndex;
            this->CurrentCharInCurrentLineIndex = -1;
        }
        token_tmp += chr;
        if (!IsInStc && IsLangDelim(chr)) IterWhile = false;
    }
    if (token_tmp.size() > 1 && System::Text::EndsWith(token_tmp, ";") || System::Text::EndsWith(token_tmp, " ")) token_tmp.pop_back();
    ++this->NbrOfTokens;
    location_t pos;
    pos.char_pos = this->CurrentCharInCurrentLineIndex;
    pos.filename = this->CurrentFilename;
    pos.line = this->CurrentLineIndex;
    SetToken_t(&ret, token_tmp, TokenList::ToToken(token_tmp), pos);
    return ret;
}
```

Here is the function IsLangDelim :

```
bool IsLangDelim(char chr) {
    return (chr == ' ' || chr == '\t' || TokenList::IsSymbol(CharToString(chr)));
}
```

TokenList is a namespace that contains the list of tokens, as well as some functions (like IsSymbol in this case).

I have already tried other versions of this method, but the result is almost always the same.

Do you have any idea how to improve this method?

Comment: As a general advise, I would recommend to take a look at the Roslyn source code. You'll find a good example of tokenizer there.

Comment: @Evgeny: Thanks for the advice. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your problem is using a `std::regex`. Understanding the syntax is, in the beginning, a little bit difficult, but after you understand it, you will always use it.

And, it is designed to find tokens.

The specific critera can be expressed in the regex string.

For your case I will use: `std::regex re(R"#((\w+|\d+|[;:\(\)\{\}\+\-\*\/\%\=]))#");`

This means:

- Look for one or more characters (That is a word)
- Look for one or more digits (That is a integer number)
- Or look for all kind of meaningful operators (Like '+', '-', '{' and so on)

You can extend the regex for all the other stuff that you are searching. You can also regex a regex result.

Please see example below. That will create your shown output from your provided input.

And, your described task is only one statement in main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>

// Our test data (raw string) .
std::string testData(
R"#(func main() {
    var MyVar : integer = 3+2;
}
)#");

std::regex re(R"#((\w+|\d+|[;:\(\)\{\}\+\-\*\/\%\=]))#");

int main(void)
{
    std::copy(
        std::sregex_token_iterator(testData.begin(), testData.end(), re, 1),
        std::sregex_token_iterator(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n")
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While regex does solve the issue, it's way to slow for parsing files in any semi-production environment.

Comment: That's correct. I agree. For productive code I use lex/yacc since 30years (Yes, on Unix machines, when there was no PC). Lex uses also regular expressions, but compile time evaluated and not runtime evaluated like std::regex. But for the vast majority of people here, it will be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Although in my opinion lexing is such an easy issue, that it's simpler to write it by hand, rather to deal with installation of any external tool. and code based lexing is the fastest you can get. It requires expertise to write one well, so if the performance is not top priority, tools are probably a best idea.

Answer (score 0):

You try to parse using single loop, which makes the code very complicated. Instead i suggest something like this:

```
struct token { ... };
struct lexer {
  vector<token> tokens;
  string source;
  unsigned int pos;

  bool parse_ident() {
    if (!is_alpha(source[pos])) return false;
    auto start = pos;
    while(pos < source.size() && is_alnum(source[pos])) ++pos;
    tokens.push_back({ token_type::ident, source.substr(start, pos - start) });
    return true;
  }
  bool parse_num() { ... }
  bool parse_comment() { ... }
  ...
  bool parse_whitespace() { ... }
  void parse() {
    while(pos < source.size()) {
      if (!parse_comment() && !parse_ident() && !parse_num() && ... && !parse_comment()) {
        throw error{ "unexpected character at position " + std::to_string(pos) };
      }
    } 
  }
```

This is standard structure i use, when lexing my files in any scripting language i've written. Lexing is usually greedy, so you don't need to bother with regex (which is effective, but slower, unless some crazy template based implementation). Just define your `parse_*` functions, make sure they return false, if they didn't parsed a token and make sure they are called in correct order.

Order itself doesn't matter usually, but:

1. operators needs to be checked from longest to shortest
2. number in style `.123` might be incorrectly recognized as `.` operator (so you need to make sure, that after `.` there is no digit.
3. numbers and identifiers are very lookalike, except that identifiers starts with non-number.